# How to put multiple circle overlays on a WP7 Bing Map control?

Tags: xaml, windows-phone-7, bing-maps, geometry

I want to put a number of (transparent) circles on a Bing Map Control as overlays. Think about a "blast radius" or "sphere of influence" kind of thing. I'll need at least two dozen of these circles on the map, together with some other polygons, so making sure performance does not suffer and the maps continues to be easily manipulative seems key here.

So far I can think of three options (of which I tried two):

- Add n-sided `MapPolygon` instances to the map for each circle. Tried this, and works fine in principle. However, the number of vertices per polygon is a bit of pickle. Too little, and when you zoom in it looks hideous. Too many, and performance will start to suffer.
- Add `Pushpin` instances for each circle, and style/template them as circle that are centered around the pushpin location. Seems to work, except that the size of the cicle is then fixed in screen size, not map size. So when you zoom, the circles stay the same size on screen, while they should zoom with the map. *Can you bind the size of `Ellipse` control (in the template in the style I use) to the `Zoom` of the parent map control in some way..?*
- Create a custom subclass of `MapShapeBase` to represent each circle. This implementation could dynamically change the number of vertices used to draw the polygon depending on whether the shape is visible on the map or not (=inside current view port) and what the zoom level is. That is, if map shapes have access to this information. I haven't tried this option yet.

What have you used? What would you use? How would you work around the problems mentioned above, *especially binding a property of a control in a template used in a style to a parent control property using XAML*? Or do you have any other options I could try to get this to work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you move away from the Bing Map Controls and start using the ESRI Silverlight / WP7 Toolkit. They have much more controls available that you can use out of the box.

http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgismobile/10.0/apis/windowsphone/

Here are all the samples: http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgismobile/10.0/apis/windowsphone/samples/start.htm

You will need an account to download the SDK, but it's free (to register and download).

Comment: Here is some more information. You should generate Graphics, assign Symbols to them and then add them to a GraphicsLayer and add this to your list of Layers. The Symbol can be anything. A default symbol (icon), or a circle, or something else you defined in xaml.

Comment: PS: all the other solutions given, will cost you a lot of time to calculate and match the correct position on the earth. You won't have these problems when you use the ESRI toolkit / SDK.

Comment: I'll try again on my own (now on Mango; Bing Maps controls is said to have received some tweaking and performance upgrades), but trying out the ASRI Silverlight / WP7 Toolkit is on my list of things to try. Thanks!

Comment: Quick question: does the ESRI Toolkit read/handle shape files in any way...? #fingerscrossed

Comment: currently the ESRI Toolkit for Windows Phone can just consume ArcGIS Server (REST) endpoints. But you could host your shapefile on ArcGIS online and consume it like that. AFAIK you can't read in a local shapefile and display it. ESRI has a lot of maps available for 'free' use. Go to arcgis.com and make an account and look at the online tool and the maps they have available. Let me know if you need some more specific help. I can send you some links if needed.

Comment: I can't find the price on ArcGIS website. Is it free to use their API?

Comment: no i discovered it's not and there isn't really any good price model for single developers.

Answer (score 1):

In RunKeeper we used the first option and bound the `Locations` property to a `LocationCollection` with 360 points created as follows:

```
protected void UpdateAccuracyCircle()
{
    var location = this.CurrentLocation;
    if (null != location)
    {
        var lat = location.Latitude * (Math.PI / 180);
        var lng = location.Longitude * (Math.PI / 180);
        var d = (this.Accuracy / 1000.0) / Constants.EarthRadius;
        var circle = new LocationCollection();

        for (int x = 0; x <= 360; x++)
        {
            var brng = x * (Math.PI / 180);
            var latRadians =
                Math.Asin(
                    Math.Sin(lat) *
                    Math.Cos(d) + 
                    Math.Cos(lat) * 
                    Math.Sin(d) * 
                    Math.Cos(brng));
            var lngRadians = 
                lng + 
                Math.Atan2(
                    Math.Sin(brng) * Math.Sin(d) * Math.Cos(lat),
                    Math.Cos(d) - Math.Sin(lat) * Math.Sin(latRadians));

            circle.Add(
                new GeoCoordinate(
                    latRadians * (180 / Math.PI),
                    lngRadians * (180 / Math.PI)));
        }

        Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() => this.AccuracyCircle = circle);
    }
}
```

In this instance we're only dealing with one circle (for the accuracy indication), so might not be particularly efficient if you need multiple circles.

Given that the logic for creating the circle is in code in this example, I think you could easily adjust the logic to use more/fewer points based on the ZoomLevel to meet option 3.

Comment: Thanks! Creating the actual circle polygon(s) is not actually my problem. Getting this to work without performance problems (a 360-sided polygon for each circle would be... suboptimal I think) is. Would like to have the number of sides of polygons used to be variable by visibility/zoomlevel, or style Pushpins as circles in geo size, not screen size. But thanks very much for the quick reply.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest using a canvas as an overlay with a transparent background and then add ellipse objects to that, using a similar technique as described [here](http://www.kirupa.com/blend_silverlight/animations_code_pg1.htm).

Only trick will be to get the aspect ratio of the canvas aligned with the map control as it's displayed / updated and the positioning of the ellipses relative to the coordinates your aiming for.